# Why don't the collect and each methods work the same way with the succ method?

Tags: ruby

`["H", "A", "L"].collect {|x| x.succ } # => ["I", "B", "M"]` but

```
["H", "A", "L"].each {|x| x.succ } # => ["H", "A", "L"]
```

What is causing the difference in output here?

The `succ` method increments a string.

Answer (score 6):

The result of the block in [Array#each](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Array.html#method-i-each) are completely discarded, the result of `each` is the array itself (that's why you get the original `["H","A","L"]`). Here you want a `collect/map` as you show in the first snippet (which creates a new array and leaves the old one untouched).

The output of `each` is discarded because `each` is the classical imperative *for-loop*: you need to do some kind of side-effect (read from a file, print to screen, update an array/hash, ...) to effectively do something.

My advice is to avoid `each` unless there is a good reason for it. I mean, it's ok to use each to write lines to a file, for example, but never to emulate a `map`, `select`, `inject`, or other [FP abstractions](http://code.google.com/p/tokland/wiki/RubyFunctionalProgramming).

Comment: would you explain a little more, why is the output discarded with Enumerable#each?

Comment: That's the way it works. Use `each` when you're interested in the operation; use `collect` or its synonym `map` when you're interested in the output. Read the docs for more info.

Answer (score 1):

An alternate approach using each_char:

```
"HAL".each_char.map {|x| x.succ } # => ["I", "B", "M"]
```

or just map

```
["H","A","L"].map {|x| x.succ } # => ["I", "B", "M"]
```

Cheers :)

Comment: the first can also be written: "HAL".chars.map(&:succ)

Comment: nice one tokland...and that inspires this: "HAL".chars.map(&:succ).inject(""){|s,c| s << c} # => "IBM"

Comment: with join:  "HAL".chars.map(&:succ).join #=> "IBM"

Comment: "HAL".chars.inject(""){|s,c| s << c.succ} for an inject bassed solution.